# Combining dimensions with non overlapping data (Tableau)

Tags: excel, tableau-api

My data source is an 'outer join' of data from three distinct excel sheets with non-overlapping data. Each sheet has the same fields for filtering and the same two dimensions for a desired graph, `ID` and `Reason`. I want to create a basic bar chart that has the `Reason`s across all three sheets on a single horizontal axis and a CountD(`ID`) on the vertical axis.

How can I combine the three separate dimensions into one dimension? Should I use a calculated field?

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with a bit more digging I was able to figure this one out (with the help of the second half of [this post](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/combine-your-data-files-union-tableau-93-48891)

I just needed to select all three of the dimensions I wanted to combine, right click, hover over "Transform", and then select "Merge Mismatched Fields".

This worked was the proper solution for me because there were no overlapping  data in the three relevant columns. Wherever one had a value, the other two were always null.

Note: I am using Tableau 10